# Get syncJobs in microsoft graph returning unknown error through c# code

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get sync jobs through c# code but getting unknown internal error. Here is code snippet :

var jobs = graphClient.ServicePrincipals["id"].Synchronization.Jobs.Request().GetAsync().Result;
getting Null jobs from this code.

Comment: Please give more details of the error and code.

Comment: var jobs = graphClient.ServicePrincipals["id"].Synchronization.Jobs.Request().GetAsync().Result; is returning Null jobs

Answer (score 2):

When you want to [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/synchronization-synchronizationjob-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp#code-try-1) syncJobs, you need to add `Directory.ReadWrite.All` Delegated permission to app registered in Azure AD.

BTW, if you want to get syncJobs you could use the code as below:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var synchronizationJob = await graphClient.ServicePrincipals["{id}"].Synchronization.Jobs["{jobId}"]
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```